# Выгрузка данных из Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-database, firebase-android

Необходимо выгрузить данные из Firebase DB. Сейчас данные выгружаются, но не правильно.
В цикле пробегаю по кадру snapshot. Он выводит только дату события. Потому что в ветке, date только 1.
В кадре есть информация о всех каталогах в этом подкаталоге. Скрин бд ниже. Пытался ещё раз проитерировать snaphot. Цикл в цикле. Но не могу обратится напрямую к нужным каталогам. Не знаю, можно ли сделать то что я хочу... Или нужно убирать лист date из каталога. Нужно чтобы выводилась и дата и время и событие. Вот код с обращением к бд и пробежке по кадру.

```
 reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events").child(globalVariable.getIdgroup());
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            elist.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Events events = snapshot.getValue(Events.class);
                elist.add(events);
            }
            eadapter = new EventsAdapter(getContext(), elist);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(eadapter);

        }
```

Скриншоты бд, и отладки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так у вас в базе поля date, ev1, ev2, в классе `Events` соответственно должны быть такие же. Если вы хотите вместо ev1, ev2... иметь массив (что более логично), то в базе должна быть отдельная коллекция, которую в классе Events также необходимо описать не как отдельное поле event, а как список...

Comment: Да, но чтобы все ev1,ev2,ev(n) собрать в 1 ArrayList, их надо итерировать отдельно.

Comment: Не надо ничего итерировать отдельно. Повторите структуру в firebase'е. Сделайте в firebase вложенный список например, eventlist https://ibb.co/sKNLq39 И в Events добавьте свойство List<Event> eventlist, где Event содержит поля event и time. получите список без итерирования...